# Getting EC2 Windows Password from instances when using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I'm struggling to get the password from a couple of new ec2 instances when using terraform. Been reading up through a couple of posts and thought i had it but not getting anywhere.

Here's my config:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami = "ami-06f9d25508c9681c3"
  count         = "2"
  instance_type = "t2.small"
  key_name = "mykey"
  vpc_security_group_ids =["sg-98d190fc","sg-0399f246d12812edb"]
  get_password_data = "true"
}

output "public_ip" {
    value = "${aws_instance.example.*.public_ip}"
}

output "public_dns" {
    value = "${aws_instance.example.*.public_dns}"
}

output "Administrator_Password" {
    value = "${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.*.password_data, 
file("mykey.pem"))}"
}
```

Managed to clear up all the syntax errors but now when running get the following error:

```
PS C:\tf> terraform apply
aws_instance.example[0]: Refreshing state... (ID: i-0e087e3610a8ff56d)
aws_instance.example[1]: Refreshing state... (ID: i-09557bc1e0cb09c67)

Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* output.Administrator_Password: At column 3, line 1: rsadecrypt: argument 1 
should be type string, got type list in:

${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.*.password_data, file("mykey.pem"))}
```

Comment: I guess you might need 2 `Administrator_Password` outputs, identifying each on list `value = "${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.*.password_data[0], 
file("mykey.pem"))}"`

Comment: Dropped it down to one instance to keep it simple and get it working.  Using this `config output "Administrator_Password" {
 value = "${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.password_data,file("C:/TF/mykey.pem"))}"
}` but end up with the following response - `Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* output.Administrator_Password: rsadecrypt: crypto/rsa: decryption error in:

${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.password_data,file("C:/TF/mycert.pem"))`

Comment: Able to get the password with the key from the aws cli so know the key is correct `aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id  i-09557bc1e0cb09c67 --priv-launch-key mykey.pem`  Just need to figure out the terraform setup

Answer (score 3):

This error is returned because `aws_instance.example.*.password_data` is a list of the `password_data` results from each of the EC2 instances. Each one must be decrypted separately with `rsadecrypt`.

To do this in Terraform v0.11 requires using `null_resource` as a workaround to achieve a "for each" operation:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = 2

  ami                    = "ami-06f9d25508c9681c3"
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  key_name               = "mykey"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-98d190fc","sg-0399f246d12812edb"]
  get_password_data      = true
}

resource "null_resource" "example" {
  count = 2

  triggers = {
    password = "${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.*.password_data[count.index], file("mykey.pem"))}"
  }
}

output "Administrator_Password" {
    value = "${null_resource.example.*.triggers.password}"
}
```

From Terraform v0.12.0 onwards, this can be simplified using the new `for` expression construct:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = 2

  ami                    = "ami-06f9d25508c9681c3"
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  key_name               = "mykey"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-98d190fc","sg-0399f246d12812edb"]
  get_password_data      = true
}

output "Administrator_Password" {
  value = [
    for i in aws_instance.example : rsadecrypt(i.password_data, file("mykey.pem"))
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but still running into errors.  'Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:
* null_resource.example: 2 error(s) occurred:
* null_resource.example[1]: index 1 out of range for list aws_instance.example.*.password_data (max 1) in:
${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.*.password_data[count.index], file("mycert.pem"))}
* null_resource.example[0]: rsadecrypt: crypto/rsa: decryption error in:
${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.example.*.password_data[count.index], file("mycert.pem"))}'

Comment: I also tried dropping it down to one instance and still hit the same issue around the certificate as suspected I might be trying to complicate it with 2 instances.

Comment: I am getting this error while executing the above expressions                              
     Error: Attempt to get attribute from null value
│ 
│   on ec2.tf line 18, in output "Administrator_Password":
│   18:     for i in aws_instance.windowstest : rsadecrypt(i.password_data, file("/home/qDownloads/terraform-key.pem"))
│ 
│ This value is null, so it does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on ec2.tf line 18, in output "Administrator_Password":
│   18:     for i in aws_instance.windowstest : rsadecrypt(i.password_data, fi