# How to fix "rsadecrypt: argument 1 should be type string, got type list in:"

Tags: terraform

At the beginning I want to build just one windows machine, so this code works fine at the beginning:

```
output "Administrator_Password" {
  value = "${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.new_instance.password_data, file("${module.ssh_key_pair.private_key_filename}"))}"
}
```

But once I introduce `count` to `resource "aws_instance" "new_instance" {`, I have to add `*` to the expression `aws_instance.new_instance.*.password_data`.

But then I start to get this error:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* output.Administrator_Password: At column 3, line 1: rsadecrypt: argument 1 should be type string, got type list in:

${rsadecrypt(aws_instance.new_instance.*.password_data, file("${module.ssh_key_pair.private_key_filename}"))}
```

I have tried the `count.index` syntax but they do not work. The variants are

```
aws_instance.new_instance.password_data[count.index]
```

and

```
aws_instance.new_instance.password_data[aws_instance.new_instance.count.index]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting EC2 Windows Password from instances when using Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201504/getting-ec2-windows-password-from-instances-when-using-terraform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use template_file resource,

```
data "template_file" "decrypted_keys" {
  count = "${aws_instance.new_instance.count}"

  template = "${rsadecrypt(element(aws_instance.new_instance.*.password_data, count.index), file(module.ssh_key_pair.private_key_filename))}"
}

output "Administrator_Password" {
  value = "${data.template_file.decrypted_keys.*.rendered}"
}
```